# select rows not contained in table

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I have a table containing an ID as follows:

```
ID
----------------
10000V9F
10000V9O
10000VAh
10000VCB
10000VDn
10000VE9
10000VF4
10000VFE
10000VFH
10000VFW
10000VG9
```

Now I want to get all the data from another table that has none of these IDs. Therefor I create a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 where ID NOT IN (...)
```

Where `...` is a list of IDs a got via another query and that contains all the previously mentioned IDs from the first table. This list is defined as follows:

```
string idString = "'" + String.Join("'", this.GetIDsForTableNames(newTables).ToArray()) + "'";
```

The method `GetIDsForTableNames` may also return an empty list containing no elements at all. In this case the resulting query from above would lead to something like this:

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 where ID NOT IN ('')
```

Which I expect to return ALL the IDs from `TABLE1`. But instead NONE is returned. However when I fire `SELECT * from TABLE1 where ID NOT IN ('a')` where `a` is just a dummy all rows from `TABLE1` are returned.

So how can I handle the list-is-empty-case appropriatly or why doesn´t it work with an empty list?

EDIT: Okay, it seems some surroundings are not clear enough. As I´m not building the SQL-string self (this is done via 3rd-party tool), I can only modify the whereclause which is only some kind of minimzed SQL (subqueries and joins NOT supported). This is why I used the `ID IN`-technic.

Comment: How are you building the select command itself (not the idString)?

Comment: When the Id list is empty and IN('') doesn't work, I am afraid that the only dirty solution is to put in idstring a non empty value that would never be encountered as Id.

Comment: @Graffito That´s what I already mentioned with the dummy-value. Yeap, that´s propbably the way going.

Comment: I suppose that you use an oracle database. This behavior occurs because in Oracle empty strings behave as null values and inserting a NULL in a IN expression doesn't provide results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why doesn´t it work with an empty list?

That's because of 2 things:

**1. Oracle treats empty strings as null values**

So your query:

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 where ID NOT IN ('')
```

is in fact equivalent to:

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 where ID NOT IN (NULL)
```

**2. NOT IN behavior**

The `NOT IN` clause can be simplified as a check of all values against the list.
If the result of any value is `TRUE` (the value is in the list) or `NULL`, then the test fails.

All the checks returns `NULL`, so your query doesn't return any row.

This is why it doesn't work with an empty list in Oracle.

Back to your question:

> how can I handle the list-is-empty-case appropriatly

You have to find another way than getting the IDs and including them in a `NOT IN` clause.
As you don't have any control on the query, you will have to include details on your 3-party tool and hope there is a workaround.

More info about this:

- [Oracle/PLSQL: Difference between an empty string and a null value](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/empty_null.php)
- [Understand how NULLs affect IN and EXISTS](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-how-nulls-affect-in-and-exists/5319615/)
- [NULLs in Oracle](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.ch/2005/06/nulls-in-oracle.html)

---

**Note:** *(just in case some SQL Server users find this post)*
If you were using SQL Server, your query would work because empty strings are not processed as `NULL`.
Even the second query `SELECT * from TABLE1 where ID NOT IN (NULL)` would work assuming you have set `ANSI_NULLS` to `OFF`. Such a setting is not available in Oracle.

Comment: Really good answer, did not know that oracle has such a special handling.